# How to check if in multidimensional array exist multiple key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to check that some value exist in multidimensional array.

For exmaple I have array:

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
   [reservation_start] => 12:05:00
   [reservation_end] => 12:40:00 
 )
 [1] => Array (
   [reservation_start] => 13:15:00
   [reservation_end] => 13:50:00
 )
 [2] => Array (
   [reservation_start] => 12:05:00
   [reservation_end] => 13:50:00
   )
)
```

And I have both values of subarray like:
$reservation_start = 13:15:00, and $reservation_end = 13:50:00
How to check whether both values are exists in specific subarray?

EDIT:
So if I have two variables with hours like:
$service_start = 13:15:00
$service_end = 13:50:00

My multidimensional array has a subarray with these data two variables at the same time, so it should, for example, return true.
In my case only array [1] meets these conditions  because contain both correct values

Comment: this might be what you are looking for: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=jY_fCoIwFMbvB3uHMUQXeDEzb2bWg4SMlQslUtmmJOG75z_MiMLv5nDO-X185-yPZVpCAIEllBINitAJAtRpKr0cJbVUtTBZkXNthDIOig4Ie1tGA0Ypdn-wMk9mckd7cgRjd32Gz7yVGT4L6IKMIYjD_rNroaS4pGT6UGhk6eo8NBv0HOHsSoYBv8mGy0emjSb46yTsLq22jf57utM-HHNar1oonlT3krz34bhtIWhf&v=8.1.3

Comment: @caramba not exactly, because I have to check if these subarrays contain the values that I have under the variables $reservation_start = 13:15:00, and $reservation_end = 13:50:00

Comment: Are you trying to see if there's a single subarray matching both of those values, or if they're both found among any of the inner arrays?

Comment: I try check if there's a single subarray matching both of those values

Comment: Okay. Do the subarrays in your real data actually contain any other keys that you've omitted from the example to make the question more concise, or is it really just reservation_start and reservation_end?

Comment: Subarrays always contain the same keys but different values.
I want to check if the subarray contains both the values I have under the variables

Comment: to me your question is not 100% clear and you haven't shown anything of what you have tried (which would be good for future questions and often also explains the problem you are facing) anyway maybe this answers your question: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUkksKkqsVLBViOblUgACKAUC6kWpxalFZYklmfl58cUliUUl6gq2dgpKhkZWBqZWBgZKOjjUpualwFWaGIBUQhTG6hBvh7GVIZF2GFuZGiCpJMESMgzn5Yq1BgVbWn5RamJyhgY0-BKLFVSKS5PAHE2FaojizDSNvNKcHAVFW4RkNBa3xCqoqSkQUAlyUSzcZBAoSyyKTynNLdBAWGwNka3l5aoFAA%2C%2C&v=8.1.3

Comment: My function generates some array like in my post. As a result, it gets a multidimensional array, each subarray contains two elements. In my second function, I have two variables with hours, start time and end time. My array has many of these values in sub-arrays. I have to check if any array has both of these values at the same time

Comment: it's still not clear. do you mean you have to check if every subarray has a value set in `reservation_start ` and `reservation_end` or do you need to compare those two values if they are the same? what should your result look like?

Comment: @caramba I edited my questin

Comment: @mm42 what is a correct value? why does only `array[1]` meet the conditions? which conditions? why are those values correct? why are the other values wrong?

Comment: Because only and exclusively the array [1] contains both values 13:15:00 and 13:50:00.
The others do not contain both of these values at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for instance:

```
$arr = [
   0 => ['reservation_start' => 0],
];
var_dump(isset($arr[0]['reservation_start']));
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data you're searching only contains those two keys, you can use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Make an array using your two variables, and use it as the "needle" parameter.

```
$target = [
    'reservation_start' => $reservation_start,
    'reservation_end' => $reservation_end
];

$found = in_array($target, $data);
```

[There's an example in the PHP manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#refsect1-function.in-array-examples) (See "Example #3 in_array() with an array as needle")

I made an example you can try online here: https://3v4l.org/XRAAN